# Crm 2011 get custom entity record attribute without early bound types

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, early-binding

I'm searching for a method of retrieving the custom entity attribute 
without generating early bind types with crmsvcutil.

Is there any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to generate early bound types to retrieve entity data from CRM. You can work with a type called Entity (which is similar to the DynamicEntity of CRM4).

The SDK has some examples about how to work with late bound entities [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328416.aspx).

This entity class is not strongly typed (unlike early-bound entities generated from crmsvcutil) so you have to perform casts yourself. There is a method on Entity which will help with this. The following code might give you some idea about how to retrieve a late-bound entity.

```
IOrganizationService service = GetOrganizationService();
var entity = service.Retrieve(entityName,
                                entityId,
                                new ColumnSet(new[]
                                                {
                                                    stringAttributeName,
                                                    intAttributeName,
                                                    floatAttributeName,
                                                    boolAttributeName,
                                                    optionSetAttributeName,
                                                    entityReferenceAttributeName,
                                                }));
var stringValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<string>(stringAttributeName);
var intValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<int?>(intAttributeName);
var floatValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<double?>(floatAttributeName);
var boolValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<bool?>(boolAttributeName);
var optionSetValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>(optionSetAttributeName);
var entityReferenceValue = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>(entityReferenceAttributeName);
```